# How to automatically archive to Thunderbird Local Folder?

Tags: thunderbird, imap, archiving

I have set up a new account with IMAP protocol, and configured archiving this way:

```
Account settings -> myaccount@new.server
                 -> Copies & Folders
                 -> Messages Archives
                 [x] Keep messages archives in
                     [x] "Archives" folder on: -> Local Folders
```

(I have also tried

```
                 [x] Keep messages archives in
                     [x] Other: -> "Archives" on Local Folders
```

instead.)

But it does not work. When I..

- pick an e-mail in `myaccount@new.server/Inbox` folder
- right click -> `archive`

I expect that:

- the e-mail is moved to `Local Folders/Archives/2020/2020-01`
- the e-mail is no longer in `myaccount@new.server/Inbox`

But instead:

- new (unwanted) folders `myaccount@new.server/Archives/2020/2020-01` are created (both locally and distantly)
- the e-mail is moved to these new folders instead (both locally and distantly)
- the e-mail is not even locally copied in `Local Folders/Archives`

The problem persists after I `compact folders` and restart Thunderbird.

What could be wrong?
How to fix this behaviour?
Is the problem rather related to Thunderbird or to `new.server` IMAP configuration?
How to investigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, got it. Just make sure that you also do the same parametrization for **every identity** associated to your `account@new.server`:

```
Account settings -> myaccount@new.server
                 -> Manage Identities...
                 -> <pick one, and repeat for each>
                     -> Edit...
                     -> Copies & Folders
                     -> Messages archives
                     [x] Keep messages archives in
                         [x] "Archives" folder on: -> Local Folders
```